# Can't change element's border colour on hover

Tags: css, button, css-transitions

I am trying to change the triangle's colour when the user hovers over the button.

I have tried applying a style to the hovered child element of the button and it did not work.

How can I get the triangle to change colour on button hover with the normal button's background colour.

**My Code:**

```css
#contact-form .submit {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #3f3f3f;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 16px 40px;
    width: 115px;
}

.contact-submit a {
 color: #222;
    font-weight: normal;
}

#contact-form > .contact-submit > .hvr-bubble-float-top {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  top: 0;
}

#contact-form > .contact-submit > .hvr-bubble-float-top:before {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  left: calc(50% - 10px);
  top: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #666 transparent;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
}

#contact-form > .contact-submit > .hvr-bubble-float-top:hover, #contact-form > .contact-submit > .hvr-bubble-float-top:focus, #contact-form > .contact-submit > .hvr-bubble-float-top:active {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
  transform: translateY(10px);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #666;
  border-color: transparent transparent #666 transparent !important;
}

#contact-form > .contact-submit > .hvr-bubble-float-top:hover:before, #contact-form > .contact-submit > .hvr-bubble-float-top:focus:before, #contact-form > .contact-submit > .hvr-bubble-float-top:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
  transform: translateY(-10px);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5000;
}
```

```html
<p class="contact-submit">
                 <a id="contact-submit" class="submit hvr-bubble-float-top" href="#">SEND MESSAGE</a>
                </p>
```

Comment: You're missing `#contact-form` in your snippet. Nothing is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the `border-bottom-color` for `.hvr-bubble-float-top:hover:before`. Using your styling as a base:

```
#contact-form > .contact-submit > .hvr-bubble-float-top:hover:before,
#contact-form > .contact-submit > .hvr-bubble-float-top:focus:before,
#contact-form > .contact-submit > .hvr-bubble-float-top:active:before {
    …
    border-bottom-color: red;
}
```

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/f4gzzerq/).

Comment: Thank you so much. This was the fix.

Answer (score 0):

The only property that CSS is trying to transition is `transform` because of this code:

```
transition-property: transform;
```

There's a lot going on in the code you posted but the first thing to try would be to change that to:

```
transition-property: transform, border-color;
```

and give it another shot.